# Need an encrypted online source code backup service

Tags: version-control, backup, remote-backup

Please note this is not a question about online/hosted SVN services.

I am working on a home based, solo developer, project that now has commercial significance and it is time to think about remote source code backup. There is no need for file level check in/out, all I need is once a day or once a week directory level snapshot to remote storage. Automatic encryption would be a bonus to protect my IP.

What I have in mind is some sort of GUI interface app that will squirt a source code snapshot off to an Amazon S3 bucket on an automatic schedule.

(My development PC runs on MS Windows.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of encrypted backup solutions that use S3. Perhaps the best known is [Jungledisk](http://www.jungledisk.com/). I would *highly* recommend using a version control system with a private repository, however; you'll be glad you did the first time you realize you need to recover some code from 2 revisions ago, or need to reproduce a bug that occurred in a previous release of your software. [Github](https://github.com/) offer private git repositories starting at an extremely reasonable price; you have full access control. There's a good overview of private SVN repositories [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791/free-online-private-svn-repositories).

Also, you don't need to 'protect your IP' - your IP is protected by copyright law. You might need or want to protect the confidentiality of your source, but if I was given the choice between using source control and using encryption, I personally would choose source control in a heartbeat, then choose a private repository host that I trust not to compromise my data.

Comment: @Nick - A source control repository is long overdue for my project. I have been delaying because I want to host this on MS's latest source control system provided in VS2010. Now that Windows 7 is out I can buy a new dev PC and rebuild my dev environment.

Answer (score 2):

I have some confidential data I might need on the road (mostly usernames/passwords) stored in a [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org) volume located in my [DropBox](http://www.getdropbox.com) with a copy on my [SkyDrive](http://windowslive.com/online/skydrive)

Answer (score 0):

S3 is good and easy to automate but as a developer the time between backups or checkins can be very costly if something goes wrong such as if both <strike>RAID 0</strike> RAID 1 hard drives overheat and pack it in at the same time :(.

I use [LiveMesh](https://www.mesh.com/welcome/default.aspx) which keeps all my important files in sync in near real-time. It's zero effort to use once set up and the set up is also very simple. You also get the added bonus of having your files acessible remotely should it ever be needed. The only caveat is if you're on an internet connection where you have very low upload limits.

Comment: @sipwiz - Thanks for the LiveMesh pointer. Re. RAID-0. Think you meant RAID-1 because a single drive failure on RAID-0 would lead to failure.